# Named Life Cycle Inventory

Tags: brightway

How do I get the *named* Life Cycle Inventory of an activity?

Let's say I'm calculating the Life Cycle Assessment of an activity:

```
act = [
       act for act in ei391cf
       if 'benzaldehyde production' == act['name']
       and 'RER' == act['location']
       ]

lca = bw.LCA(
    {act[0]: 1},
    ('ReCiPe 2016 v1.03, midpoint (H)',
     'water use', 'water consumption potential (WCP)')
    )

lca.lci()
lca.lcia()
```

... I understand that `lca.biosphere_dict` returns the biosphere flows of the Life Cycle Inventory. However, it only lists the codes of the biosphere flows rather than their names and categories. I could write my own function to determine the names and categories, but it must be such a basic task that I am sure there is a function for it.

In fact, I have come across [`get_labelled_inventory`](https://docs.brightway.dev/en/latest/api/bw2analyzer/lci/index.html#bw2analyzer.lci.get_labeled_inventory), but I can't get it to work.

I tried `ba.lci.get_labeled_inventory(lca)` but it just returns `AttributeError: module 'bw2analyzer' has no attribute 'get_labeled_inventory'`.

Answer (score 1):

First off, please always be careful with something like:

```
act = [
   act for act in ei391cf
   if 'benzaldehyde production' == act['name']
   and 'RER' == act['location']
   ]
```

You should at least check the length of this list with e.g. `assert len(act) == 1`. In Brightway 2.5 you can also do `bw2data.get_node(name='benzaldehyde production', location='RER', database=ei391cf['name'])`.

In Brightway 2.5 you can do `lca.to_dataframe(matrix_label='inventory')` to get an annotated pandas `Dataframe`.

In Brightway 2, you can do something similar with (not tested code):

```
from functools import lru_cache
import bw2data as bd


@lru_cache(maxsize=16000):
def cached_lookup(key):
    return bd.get_activity(key)


inventory_results = []

for row, row_key in lca.biosphere_dict.items():
    for col, col_key in lca.activity_dict.items():
        if lca.inventory[row, col] != 0:
            inventory_results.append((
                abs(lca.inventory[row, col]), 
                lca.inventory[row, col], 
                cached_lookup(row_key),
                cached_lookup(col_key)
            ))

inventory_results.sort(reverse=True)
```

Comment: Thanks. I had to update my brightway but now it works like a charm.